# Plotting year and month in a line plot R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to analyze the CO2 emission by source (industry, transport, etc.) and fuel type. I got the data from 1987 to 2022 and managed to make a plot but I got a weird graph as a result

[line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT7PB.png)

I changed it to point plot to see the problem.

[point plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTogJ.png)

Apparently I would need to accumulate the emissions of each period from all fuel types and then group them by source. How can I fix my code to do that?

Below is the link to the data I used and the info
https://www.kaggle.com/code/msyazwanonn/thailand-co2-emission-1987-2022-analysis/input

[info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z67N.png)

Initially I tried to plot using the code below:

```
library(rmgarch)
library(parallel)
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data <- read.csv("thailand_co2_emission_1987_2022.csv")
str(data)
data %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste(year, month, "01", sep = "-"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = emissions_tons, group = source, color = source)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")
```

Comment: Try with `... %>% summarise(emissions_tons = sum(emissions_tons), .by = c(date, source)) %>% ggplot(...) + ...` to aggregate your data by source and date.

Answer (score 1):

The plots shows an interaction between fuel type and source, so create a variable corresponding to it in the pipe.

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    date = as.Date(paste(year, month, "01", sep = "-")),
    source_fuel = interaction(source, fuel_type, sep = " ")
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = emissions_tons, color = source_fuel)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")
```

[image]

---

Though I believe the plot above is the one you want, another option is to facet the plot by fuel type.

```
data %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste(year, month, "01", sep = "-"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = emissions_tons, color = source)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  facet_wrap(~ fuel_type) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image]